# Is there a efficient way to iterate through?

Tags: python, loops, math

I am using python for prototyping the following expression :

```
    (n1^i1)*(n2^i2)*......*(n10^i10) = output/input_min (where I have to store i1,i2,i3,..)
```

I wrote something like this for only 3 elements.

```
        passes = []
        max_pass = 8
        for i in range(0,max_pass):
            for j in range(0,max_pass):
                for k in range(0,max_pass):
                    temp = np.array([i, j, k])
                    comp = np.round(np.prod(basis**temp), 3)
                    ratio = np.round(self.output/self.input_min, 3)
                    if comp == ratio:
                        passes.append([i, j, k])
```

Considering I know n1,n2,...,n10 and the rigth hand ratio, Is there a way I can do it without writing 10 nested loops? (i1,i2,...i10 has to be integers)

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of counters, all initialized to zero.

Form an endless loop where you increment the first counter. When the counter reaches the maximum value, reset it to zero and carry to the next counter. The next counter follows the same logics, and so on.

So the outer loop will include an inner carry propagation loop.

Processing terminates when the last counter carries.